NextJs static filenames do not match their references
I have a NextJs application.
when I use npm start it will create a static files without cache buster parameters main-app.js and reference them without main-app.js (This is working fine)
When I use npm build it will create static files with cache buster parameters main-app-d206de8cfe021259.js but still reference them without cache buster parameters main-app.js (This causes errors)
How can I update it so the build resource references match the actual file names?
